# Restore SharePoint publishing homepage to Pages/default.aspx

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2007

I have a Publishing site and the last SharePoint administrator copied /Pages/default.aspx to /default.aspx and set it as the homepage, so now I have two independent copies of the same page to maintain.

I want to delete the /default.aspx and reset the HomePage to /Pages/default.aspx.  I can set the "Welcome" page back to /Pages/default.aspx through the settings page, but the /default.aspx page still shows as the homepage in SharePoint Designer.  When I try to rename or delete it warns me that I'm deleting the homepage and x numbers of links point to it.

Any suggestions on how to effectively do this?

Should I set the welcome page and change the /default.aspx to a redirect page or just delete it?

Comment: There are probably some links on the website which reference to /default.aspx instead of /
That's probably where you get this message from.
I'd just delete the /default.aspx and set the /pages/default.aspx as the welcoming page.
Probably wise to check it first in a development environment though.
Don't know for sure if it'll break your website.

Comment: I modified /default.aspx to be a client-side redirect to /Pages/default.aspx so that existing bookmarks and links would not break. Thanks for the help